# Giving access to user-installed python distribution to another linux user

Tags: permissions, software-installation, python, multiuser

(I'm not sure exactly what SE site my question belongs, I hesitated between stackoverflow, serverfault and superuser. Feel free to give suggestions about this in the comments.)

Here is my problem:

I have two users on my linux computer, `bli` and `pquarato`. `bli` installed python3.6 locally (compiling from source with `./configure --prefix=${HOME}`). The binary is installed in `/home/bli/bin`, pip3.6 installs things in `/home/bli/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`. For instance, numpy is installed there:

```
(bli) $ pip3.6 install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/bli/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

I want `pquarato` to be able to use `bli`'s python installation. `bli` did `chmod -R a+rx` on `/home/bli/bin` and `/home/bli/.local`.

`pquarato` can use `bli`'s python3.6 binary, but it is not able to import modules installed with pip3.6:

```
(pquarato) $ /home/bli/bin/python3.6 -c 'import numpy'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

The above works without errors for `bli`.

What else should I do?

---

Note: I actually first ran into a problem when trying to get `pquarato` to use programs such as ipython3:

```
(pquarato) $ /home/bli/.local/bin/ipython3 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bli/.local/bin/ipython3", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/home/bli/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3017, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/home/bli/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3003, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bli/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3030, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/home/bli/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 659, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/home/bli/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 967, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/home/bli/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 853, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'ipython==6.2.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

I hope that the same solution will solve both the `ModuleNotFoundError` and the above `DistributionNotFound` issue.

Comment: Is the use of sudo not an option? This way pquarato can run Python as if he/she was bli.

Comment: @RamanSailopal Good suggestion, but I would prefer a safer solution.

Comment: @Christopher In some situations, it may not be convenient to ask root every time one needs to install a python package.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to `/home/pquarato/.bashrc`:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/home/bli/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages"
```

This seems to solve both issues (`ModuleNotFoundError` and `DistributionNotFound`).

The `.bashrc` file needs to be sourced before this takes effect.

This probably needs to be adapted depending on the shell that the user uses.

---

#### Edit

Setting `PYTHONPATH` doesn't seem to work with local packages that were installed as `*.egg-link` using `pip3.6 install -e`. In such cases, there is still a `ModuleNotFoundError`.